# Replace the first column of one array by first column of another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I replace the first column of array `y' by first column  of array'x'?

```
x = np.array([[1]
              [2]
              [3]
              [4]
              [5]])

y = np.array([[6, 7]
              [8, 9]
              [10, 11]
              [12, 13]
              [14, 15]])
```

The expected result would be:

```
res = np.array([[1, 7]
                [2, 9]
                [3, 11]
                [4, 13]
                [5, 15]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note is that **numpy arrays do not have rows and columns**. This isn't just a terminology issue. They genuinely don't have rows and columns. Instead, they have **dimensions** and **shape**.

For example, the following array has 1 dimension and shape `(5,)` (that's a tuple with one element).

```
z = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(z.ndim, z.shape)  # 1 (5,)
```

**In-place**

Having cleared this up, you can use `numpy` arrays to perform your operation *in place*:

```
y[:, 0][:, None] = x

print(y)

# [[ 1  7]
#  [ 2  9]
#  [ 3 11]
#  [ 4 13]
#  [ 5 15]]
```

The reason for the `[:, None]` part is to ensure that the dimensions and shape of the left-hand side of the equation are identical to those of the right-hand side.

**New array**

If you really need a new array, just copy the array and perform the same operation:

```
res = y.copy()
res[:, 0][:, None] = x
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

[glot.io fiddle](https://glot.io/snippets/ezkixddw5s)

We define a helper function `merge` to extract the elements from the lists, we take 2 arguments `a` and `b` which are lists, so we can access their values by their index. We need the first and only value from the sub-list of `x`, so we get it via `a[0]` and the second value in the sublist of `y` by accessing `b[1]` and return it as a new list containing those values.

Then we `map` our helper `merge` to both lists `x` and `y`, converting the result to a `list()` and throw it into `np.array()`

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])

y = np.array([[6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15]])

merge = lambda a,b: [a[0],b[1]] 
res = np.array(list(map(merge, x, y)))

#show results
print(res)
```